# Simulating in R- how can I make this faster?

Tags: r, while-loop, simulation, bayesian, julia

I am simulating something like [Jim Berger's applet](http://www.stat.duke.edu/~berger/applet2/applet.pdf).

The simulation works like this:  I will generate a sample `x` of size `n` either from the null distribution **N(0,1)** or from the alternative distribution **N(theta, 1)**. I will assume that the the prior probability of the null is some proportion `prop` (so the prior of the alternative is `1-prop`) and that the distribution of `theta` in the alternative is **N(0,2)** (I could change all this parameters, but this is just to start).

I want to get a large number of pvalues arround a certain range (like 2000 pvalues between 0.049 and 0.05, in the simulation this would be equivalent to z stats arround 1.96 and 1.97) from the simulation scenario described above, and to see how many came from the null and how many came from the alternative.

So far I came up with a solution like this:

```
berger <- function(prop, n){
  z=0
  while(z<=1.96|z>=1.97){
    u <- runif(1)
    if(u<prop){
      H0 <- TRUE
      x<-rnorm(n, 0, 1)
    }else{
      H0 <- FALSE
      theta <- rnorm(1, 0, 2)
      x <- rnorm(n, theta, 1)
    }
    z <- sqrt(n)*abs(mean(x))
  }
  return(H0)
}

results<-replicate(2000, berger(0.1, 100))
sum(results)/length(results) ## approximately 25%
```

It takes about 3,5 minutes. Is it possible to speed this up? How? Every answer is welcome, including integration with C.

***Update***: Parallelization can speed that up a little bit. But, I have tried the same code in Julia, and it takes only 14 seconds without any parallelization (code below).

***Update 2***: With Rcpp and parallelization it is possible to reduce the simulation to 8 seconds. See the new answer.

```
function berger(prop, n)
       z = 0 
       h0 = 0
       while z<1.96 || z > 1.97

              u = rand()

              if u < prop
                     h0 = true;
                     x = randn(n)             
              else
                     h0 = false
                     theta = randn()*2
                     x = randn(n) + theta
              end

              z = sqrt(n)*abs(mean(x))
       end

       h0
end

results = [0]

for i in 1:2000
       push!(results, berger(0.1, 100))
end

sum(results)/length(results)
```

Comment: I don't really see why it is important to consider only `0.049 < p < 0.05`? I see it is mentioned in the paper, but it doesn't make sense to me, personally.

Comment: @PascalvKooten you want to calculate the probability that H0 is true given p is approximately 0.05. Read Jim Berger's page for further detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is actually simple to speed this up using Rcpp. Combining Rcpp with parellelization, I was able to reduce the time to 8 seconds.

The `.cpp` file is something like this (using Rcpp "sugars" turns this task pretty easy - since this was the first time I used Rcpp, maybe this code is not optimal, but it did the job!):

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]


int RcppBerger(double prop, int n) {

  double z=0,theta=0, u=0;
  int h = 0;
  NumericVector x;
    while (z<1.96 || z > 1.97){
      u = R::runif(0, 1);
      if(u < prop){
        h = 1;
        x = rnorm(n);
        }else{
          h = 0;
          theta = R::rnorm(0, 2);
          x = rnorm(n, theta, 1);
          }
          z = sqrt(n)*mean(x);
          if(z<0){z = -1*z;};
    }
  return h;
}
```

Then, without parallelization, you can just use the `sourceCpp` function and the `RcppBerger` will be available in the workspace:

```
library(Rcpp)
sourceCpp("RcppBerger.cpp")
results<-replicate(2000, RcppBerger(0.1, 100))
sum(results)/length(results) ## approximately 25%
```

This already reduces the time from 3,5 minutes to arround 40 seconds. After that we can parallelize.

In Windows, this is a little tricky, it seems that you have to create a package first. But Rcpp provides a nice function to do that `Rcpp.package.skeleton`. Just put the source file in it and it will create all the necessary documents and folders:

```
Rcpp.package.skeleton("RcppBerger", cpp_files = "RcppBerger.cpp")
```

Then, after installing the package, you can parallelize with `foreach` and `doParallel`:

```
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)
library(RcppBerger)
registerDoParallel(cores=8)
results<- foreach(1:2000, .packages="RcppBerger") %dopar% RcppBerger(0.1, 100)
```

Now the simulation takes only 8 seconds.

Comment: Nice write-up, and well done with passage from `sourceCpp()` to a package.  You could now try a faster N(0,1) generator: either switch from R's default to a faster one, or plug in a faster RNG as eg one from RcppZiggurat.

Comment: There is a chart in the RcppZiggurat vignette -- 'Ahrens-Dieter' and 'Kinderman-Ramage' are both already in R and faster than the default inversion by maybe a factor of two.  RcppZiggurat can another factor of two.  Let's see if you can bring this down from 8 seconds to 5 seconds :)

Comment: @CarlosCinelli Very nice. I was inspired by this question to learn more about varieties of N(0,1) generators. I was going to update my answer, but now that I see your answer I am glad I waited. Be careful with the `RZiggurat` implementation; it didn't work for me on a Linux box. Also, I think you should probably switch the check mark to this answer, it is complete and more helpful than my answer.

Comment: Thanks, @nograpes , I think it's time for me to start studying more numerical methods and RNG!

Answer (score 3):

There might be ways to make this function a little faster (through parallelization for example), but you aren't going to get orders of magnitude difference (**edit**: *in R*). The key problem is that you are making roughly 400 million draws from the normal distribution.

This is a function that returns the average number of runs through the `while` your function takes:

```
f<-function(prop,n){
  i<-0
  z<-0
  while(z<=1.96|z>=1.97){
    i<-i+1
    u <- runif(1)
    if(u<prop){
      H0 <- TRUE
      x<-rnorm(n, 0, 1)
    }else{
      H0 <- FALSE
      theta <- rnorm(1, 0, 2)
      x <- rnorm(n, theta, 1)
    }
    z <- sqrt(n)*abs(mean(x))
  }
  return(i)
}
```

Now we can calculate how many times your function runs:

```
set.seed(1)
runs<-replicate(200,f(prop=0.1, n=100))
mean(runs) # 2034
sd(runs) # 2121
```

So, to calculate the number of draws from the normal distribution:

```
# number of replicates
# times normal distributions per replicate
# draws from each distribution
2000*mean(runs)*100
# 406,853,000 normal distribution draws
```

The `rnorm` function calls a compiled C function, and is likely to be near optimal speed. You can test the "lower bound" of making this many draws on your own machine:

```
system.time(rnorm(406853000))
# My machine:
#   user  system elapsed 
#  53.78    2.39   56.62
```

By comparison your function runs roughly four times slower:

```
system.time(replicate(2000,berger(prop=0.1,n=100)))
#    user  system elapsed 
#  210.40    0.03  211.12
```

So, your function really isn't that slow when you think about it, especially when you consider that there is overhead on each call to `rnorm`. If it is very critical that you improve the speed of this function, and you have a few cores, you can easily parallelize it in R:

```
library(parallel)
mclapply(1:2000,function(x) berger(prop=0.1,n=100))
```

Other than that, you could write a super-optimized function in C and save a few minutes, but it might not be worth it.

Comment: Thanks, really interesting, I will try to parallelize and see how it goes!

Comment: Although, I ran that applet just now, and it runs really fast, which makes me think that your function does not accurately reflect what they did. I strongly suspect that they are only making 2000 samples from the normal distribution instead of 4 million.

Comment: You can`t get 2000 p-values in 0.049- 0.05 range with just 2000 simulations, they have to run more than that. You probably ran with n=1 (the default) so it is much faster. With n=100 the applet takes about 1,5 minutes here! I have just tried the parallelization, and R took the same time!

Comment: You are correct about the simulations. Three questions about the parallelization: 1) Did you set the number of cores with `options(mc.cores=x)` where `x` is the number of cores on your machine? 2) What OS are you running? If it is Windows, you'll have to use `foreach` instead of `parallel` 3) Did you monitor the CPUs and make sure they were all active when you ran it?

Comment: I am running on Mac OS X (Mountain Lion) with an Intel Core 2 Duo; I used the default option (2 cores), I was looking at the activity monitor at those two little cpu graphs: without `parallel` only one of the graphs shows activity, while with it both graphs showed full activity!

Comment: I have just tried some coding with Julia. I am not sure if I got it right, but if I did, it took only 15 seconds!

Comment: Julia in parallel: 7 seconds!

Comment: That's lovely that you are having success with Julia. To cross-check, I ran some code in C to generate 400 million numbers, and found that it only took 3 seconds. I doubt you could achieve these speeds in R.

Comment: Yeah, but I really like R, it would be awesome to achieve this in it!

Comment: If you're comparing R to Julia, are you comparing apples to apples? It might be that Julia uses a faster, but less accurate normal RNG. OTOH, maybe that's all you need

Comment: @nograpes given that rnorm hits C pretty quickly, it's hard to believe that you coded up something equivalent that's 20x faster.

Comment: @hadley actually this was the first time I used Julia, so I am not sure how reliable it is; I ended up giving it a try because some friend said it was fast, and since I will use this code a lot, speeding it up would be useful - but if the reduction in time comes at expense of less accurate results, maybe it is not worth it, so I will definitely have to check this out!  For now I still would like to stay only within R - I was just curious about Julia - so any time reduction strategies are welcome!

Comment: Perhaps what the applet does is simulate from chi-squared?